# Unable to register Api Controller using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a WebApi that uses Simple Injector that was working perfectly fine, but i had to implement OAuth in to the project.  Now i have done that and my ApiControllers give me an error like Simple Injector has now been setup correctly

I have my Start.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        Container container = SimpleInjectorConfig.Initialize(app);

        ConfigureAuth(app, container);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
    {
        var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = container.GetInstance<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

In my SimpleInjectorConfig file i have

```
public class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    public static Container Initialize(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = GetInitializeContainer(app);

        container.Verify();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        return container;
    }

    public static Container GetInitializeContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterSingle<IAppBuilder>(app);

        container.Register<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, 
            ApiAuthorizationServerProvider>();

        // myService
        container.Register<IService, MyService>();

        // myRepository
        container.Register<IRepository, MyRepository>();

        // This is an extension method from the integration package.
        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        return container;
    }
}

public class ApiAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private IService _service;

    public ApiAuthorizationServerProvider(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(
        OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(
        OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers
            .Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        User user = _service.Query(e => e.Email.Equals(context.UserName) &&
            e.Password.Equals(context.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", 
                "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

Now my project builds fine, but i cannot test if OAuth is working yet, because i cannot connect to my ApiController.  I have not added the [Authorize] tag to the Controller yet, so i should be able to access it.

Here is my controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private IService _service;

    public MyController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // get all entities here via service
        return Ok(list);
    }

}
```

The error message i get says

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'MyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

I thought this would be registered via

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Comment: Hi, if you remove the OAuth stuff can you in the ApiController?

Comment: Setting the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` and calling `RegisterWebApiControllers` should usually do the trick. Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: I have the same setup and having the same issue. Here's the stack trace I got: at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: @Steven here's the stack trace in the innerexception: at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"

Comment: @vonv. please post a new question with a detailed description of your problem, how to reproduce and all the relevant error details (exception type, message and stack trace of the exception and all the inner exceptions).

Comment: Sounds like something isn't being instantiated or there's a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core add:

```
// Sets up the basic configuration that for integrating Simple Injector with
// ASP.NET Core by setting the DefaultScopedLifestyle, and setting up auto
// cross wiring.
services.AddSimpleInjector(_container, options =>
{
    // AddAspNetCore() wraps web requests in a Simple Injector scope and
    // allows request-scoped framework services to be resolved.
    options.AddAspNetCore()
        .AddControllerActivation();
});
```

via https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html