# LightInject - No scope when calling WebApi OWIN Identity TokenEndpointPath

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api, owin, light-inject

I have a very basic WebAPI setup with token authentication.
In the application start I do:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DependencyConfig.RegisterDependecis();
    //...
    //...
}
```

Which calls:

```
public class DependencyConfig
{
    private static ServiceContainer _LightInjectContainer;

    public static ServiceContainer LightInjectContainer
    {
        get { return _LightInjectContainer; }
    }

    public static void RegisterDependecis()
    {
        var container = new LightInject.ServiceContainer();
        container.RegisterApiControllers();
        container.ScopeManagerProvider = new PerLogicalCallContextScopeManagerProvider();
        container.EnableWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        container.Register<IRegistrationManager, RegistrationManager>(new PerScopeLifetime());

        _LightInjectContainer = container;
    }
}
```

Now, when the client invokes the token endpoint (requests a token), the provider I defined here:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    //...
    //...
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    //...
    //...
};
```

Is being used with this method:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    //...

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        //...
        // Here I get the exception!
        var registrationManager = DependencyConfig.LightInjectContainer.GetInstance<IRegistrationManager>();
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

And when I try to get the instance the following error:

> Attempt to create a scoped instance without a current scope.

I know the LightInject has a concept of Start/End scope for each request and It's actually telling me that no scope was started. But I can't seem to figure what exactly is broken and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading on of the last answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997592/dependency-injection-using-simpleinjector-and-oauthauthorizationserverprovider) question, I came up with this solution: (Starting a scope manually)

```
using(DependencyConfig.LightInjectContainer.BeginScope())
{
    IRegistrationManager manager = DependencyConfig.LightInjectContainer.GetInstance<IRegistrationManager>();
}
```

Technicaly it works, but I not sure if it's the right solution regarding whats happening behind the scenes.

Comment: That would work unless you request another IRegistrationManager later in the pipeline and expect it to be the same. Scopes are nested and Web API will create another scope for your controller.

Comment: ok, but seems like the only way to go. The solution you answered in the other question didnt work...

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation for LightInject.WebApi, there is an example shat shows how to make the HttpRequestMessage available outside the controllers. If you implement this according to the example you should be able to get to the HttpRequestMessage and then the DepenencyResolver. http://www.lightinject.net/#webapi

Comment: The example in the link won't fit my situation. For the code there to work, I have to inject the Func to the constructor, which I don't have access to. also tried a property injection instead and it didn't worked.

Comment: No, but you have your public static container that can be used to get an instance of the func. Then call the func to get the HttpRequestMessage and then get the DependencyResolver

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of LightInject

Can you try this inside your handler(SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider)

`request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IRegistrationManager)) as IRegistrationManager;`

There is actually no reason that you should expose the container as a static public member as this makes it very easy to start using the service locator anti-pattern.

Take a look at this blog post for more information.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/asp-net-web-api-and-dependencies-in-request-scope/

Comment: But this dose not compile. the only "request" object I have is context.Request which is of type IOwinRequest.
And GetDependencyScope() is a extension on HttpRequestMessage. How can I get that object here ?

Comment: Can you get to the HttpRequestMessage through the OwinContext.Environment?

Comment: context.OwinContext.Environment is an IDictionary<string,object>
I went through all of it's entries and tried to cast each one of them to HttpRequestMessage.

None would cast.

Comment: I found a solution and it works (added it as an answer). What do you think ?