# how to inject businessservice in AuthorisationServiceProvider

Tags: authentication, dependency-injection, owin

I am using OWIN for authentication i want to inject BusinessService in AuthorisationServiceProvider how can we achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.Auth.cs file, attach your ApplicationUserManager like below

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
```

And in your ApplicationUserManager use dependency injection to inject your business service like below

```
private readonly IBusinessService _businessService;

public ApplicationUserManager(IdentityRepository store, IBusinessService businessService) : base(store)
{
    _businessService = businessService;
}
```

Finally, In your DependencyRegistrar.cs file, configure your resolcer as below

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
container.RegisterType<IBusinessService, BusinessService>();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997592/dependency-injection-using-simpleinjector-and-oauthauthorizationserverprovider?answertab=votes#tab-top