# Error using Simple Injector inside OAuth GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector in my ASP.NET WEb API project to dependency injection and OAuth for authentication. For that, I need to resolve an interface inside the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method, like this:

```
using (IBusiness business = Injector.Container.GetInstance<IBusiness>())
{
}
```

But when it passes in that point, it shows me this error:

*The Business is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.*

And I am configuring my container with this singleton method:

```
public class Injector
{
    private static Container container;

    public static Container Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                container = new Container();
                container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = Lifestyle.Scoped;
                container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
            }

            return container;
        }
    }

    public static TInstance GetInstance<TInstance>() where TInstance : class
    {
        return Container.GetInstance<TInstance>();

    }
}
```

I am registering the dependencies with this code:

```
Injector.Container.Register<IBusiness, Business>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26034641/3294832) old answer is pretty much still the way to go. One might say this is a duplicate question...

Comment: Reading your question again, you're not showing all relevant code. I nowhere see any registration for IBusiness. Without such a registration the error Simple Injector throws will be very different than you're showing here. Please provide _all_ relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when I call the method `Injector.Container.GetInstance<IBusiness>()` inside `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, the container's scope was null and because of that, it throws that particular error. So it was necessary to initialize scope, and I did it using this code:

```
 using (SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(Injector.Container))
 {
     using (IBusiness business = Injector.Container.GetInstance<IBusiness>())
     {
     }
 }
```

And change the defaultScopeLifestyle to hybrid, in the container class:

```
public static Container Container
        {
            get
            {
                if (container == null)
                {
                    container = new Container();

                    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
                        new AsyncScopedLifestyle(), new WebRequestLifestyle());
                }

                return container;
            }
        }
```